# Bad System Call (core dumped) on Sybase 12.5 installation (SunOS)

Tags: installation, system, call, solaris, sap-ase

I am trying to install Sybase ASE 12.5.4 on a Sun OS Solaris 11 machine but I am getting the following messages when launching the setup file :

```
-bash-4.1$ ./setup
InstallShield Wizard

Initializing InstallShield Wizard...

Searching for Java(tm) Virtual Machine...
Bad System Call (core dumped)
```

Would you have any idea of what could cause this? I want to run a trace on this to see what's missing exactly but I cannot find how to.

Thank you for your help.
Cheers

Comment: Consider asking your question at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ . You also have a coredump file (usually written to working directory of failed app, otherwise check `coreadm`), check it by running `mdb core` and use `$c` command in debugger -- it will give you a clue, what system call you need.

Comment: I would suggest to check the Sybase compatibility matrix because Solaris 11 was released after ASE 12.5.4. They might be incompatible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply myaut. `mdb core` `finished with the following lines: ffbfee08 access+8(baeb9, 89bb4, ba4b0, ba4b0, 0, 9) and
ffbfef00 __1cMPlatformImplWcreateTempSubDirectory6F_nHSString__+0x30(baeb9, 1, 0, b8800, 0, b99a8). Any idea of what this could mean? Thank you

Comment: [Source that the access syscall was removed in Oracle Solaris 11](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28556/gkzlf.html#gkzip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your replies.

*myaut* was right when saying:

> Many system calls were deprecated in Solaris 11, access seem to be deleted

My problem therefore seemed related to a incompatibility between Sybase ASE 12.5.4 and Solaris 11 as this link shows: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc35889_1254/html/installsol/X22779.htm

Sybase ASE 12.5.4 is compatible with Solaris 2.8 (therefore Solaris 8) and I got from the SAP forum that it is 100% compatible with Solaris 9 and most likely with Solaris 10 too but clearly, it doesn't seem to be with Solaris 11.

I have managed to launch the setup from a Solaris 10 machine and it seems to work perfectly fine.

Thank you for your help.
Regards,

Answer (score 3):

**Do not use this hacks on production systems!**

Many system calls were deprecated in Solaris 11, `access` seem to be deleted:

```
$ grep access /usr/include/sys/syscall.h 
#define SYS_faccessat   45
```

Some of them are still accessible from Solaris 10 brand zones, some seem to be gone forever. Instead you have to use "at"-functions with `AT_FDCWD` param, in your case it is `faccessat`. That change was hidden by *libc*, but if Sybase brings their own *libc* things go bad, if they statically link with it, it is even worse.

If `access` is a shared library function in their own libc, you can still workaround that by using `LD_PRELOAD` hack. Write the following source:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

int access(const char *fname, int amode) {
        return (faccessat(AT_FDCWD, fname, amode, 0));
}
```

Compile it with GCC or Solaris Studio (depends on what Sybase used, probably Solaris Studio) into shared library:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC xaccess.c -o libaccess.so
```

Export `LD_PRELOAD` variable:

```
$ export LD_PRELOAD=./libaccess.so
```

And pray for luck because it may fail at another system calls, or you used wrong compiler, etc. Note that Sybase binaries may not run correctly too!

#### Have I warned about hacks on production systems? Instead, use brand Solaris 10 zones or Solaris 10 LDoms/VMs

Comment: It's C code - GCC or Solaris Studio won't matter.  What will matter is 32- and 64-bit libraries.  Set `LD_PRELOAD` with a 32-bit library on Solaris, and 64-bit binaries won't run.  Set it with a 64-bit library, and 32-bit binaries won't run.  Use either `LD_PRELOAD_64` or `LD_PRELOAD_32`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am quite surprised though, my client confirms that they have this Sybase version on a Solaris 11 system. I am running Solaris 11.2 (sparcv9), maybe it is deprecated since 11.1 or 11.2? I will try the workaround and try with other Solaris versions as well

Comment: I tried the workaround now and it won't work. I created the C file and compiled it with gcc like you suggested to do. I exported the variable and ran the setup again, I am getting the same message. I tried to export it in `LD_PRELOAD_64` as well but in vain. And I also tried running `LD_PRELOAD_64=/tmp/libaccess.so ./setup` but it won't solve the issue.

Comment: @mentinet: Why don't you use `LD_PRELOAD` like I said, at least we will see if library needs to be 32-bit. Also, like I said, there are many factors affecting my method, it is quite generic.

Comment: I did run `export LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/libaccess.so` and then the setup but it doesn't work, it does just the same. Although, when I first assign the preload in my root environnement, then did `ls` I had the following message `ld.so.1: ls: fatal: /tmp/libaccess.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 Killed` (I don't have it in my sybase environnement). I unfortunately have no idea what I am doing, so thanks a lot for your help. Any suggestion on what this means and how I could adapt your code to hopefully make it work in my situation? Thanks

Comment: Add `-m32` to compilation options when compiling `libaccess.so`

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything. I recomplied it with this option (tried from sybase user as well) and I get the same message when launching the setup. I realised when I do `export LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/libaccess.so` instead of `export LD_PRELOAD_64=/tmp/libaccess.so` that I still have this error : `ld.so.1: mdb: fatal: /tmp/libaccess.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 Killed` (when with sybase user) but only when I do `mdb core` aften attempting to run the setup.

Comment: Than probably `access()` is not came from shared library, and my method not helping Sybase :( Try Solaris 11.0 or 11.1

Comment: The `access()` **library** call is part of the POSIX standard.  (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/access.html)  It's certainly provided by `libc.so` on Solaris 11.2.  If Sybase isn't using the library call but is making the system call directly, that's a Sybase bug and all the LD_PRELOAD gyrations aren't going to help, even were you to get them correct.